# Using contents of string as condition in if statement

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, for-loop, conditional-statements

I'm trying to find a good way to take a string as input for a conditional statement so that I can check against a list of conditions by iterating through an array of them. Basically, I'm wondering if I could do something like this:

```
// Would check if foo is equal to one, bar is true, and et is a string containing 'cetera'
var conditions = ["foo==1","bar==true","bar","et=='cetera'"];
for (var i=0;i<conditions.length;i++) {
    if (conditions[i]) { console.log("Do stuff..."); }
}
```

I've thought of `eval`, but I wonder if it'd be a security risk. The files this code is in don't use PHP or any server software, but the host it runs on does have server software, and I don't know if it should be avoided.

Comment: Why are you setting conditions this way? Where are you un-setting/re-setting them that you need to check that they remain the same?

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm confused, checking if my conditions remain the same? I'm not trying to do that, but rather shorten a bunch of `if` statements into a `for` loop. I'm not doing this out of necessity, but rather to make the code shorter and easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just drop the strings.

```
var conditions = [foo == 1, bar == true, bar, et == 'cetera'];
for (var i=0;i<conditions.length;i++) {
    if (conditions[i]) {
      console.log("Do stuff...");
    }
}
```

This will populate `conditions` with a bunch of boolean values. You can then loop over it to see if any of them are true.

**Edit:** This will print "Do stuff..." every time a condition is true. So if `foo == 1` is true and `et == "cetera"`, then "Do stuff" will be printed twice. If that isn't what you want, then define an `any` function like this:

```
function any(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) if (arr[i]) return true;
  return false;
}
```

You can then use `if (any(conditions)) console.log("Do something...");`

**Edit 2:** If you initialize `conditions` way before you are checking, (and values might change) wrap each one in a function (although it is a lot more typing). So for example:

```
var conditions = [
    function() { return foo == 1; },
    function() { return bar == true; }
    // and so on...
];
```

Similarly, you would have to change `if (conditions[i]) { console.log("Do stuff..."); }` to `if (conditions[i]()) { console.log("Do stuff..."); }`

Comment: Unfortunately, the boolean values aren't representative of the condition at the current time. I need to set the array to check if the variables are something at that time, not if they were that way when the array was set. **EDIT**: I suppose if I set `conditions` right before the `for` loop, it doesn't matter, since it's current. I'm dumb. Thanks!